# How do I remove an element from a JSON object by key reference?

Tags: javascript, json, associative-array

I chose this JSON structure to store some data because I thought it would be easy to reference each object by it's key but I can't seem to correctly remove an element by key.

JSON Object:

```
[{
    "a74bb26c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2": {
        "VersionCode": "0ODD6109",
        "VersionQualifier": "",
        "ProductID": "WRAP",
    }
}, {
    "a74fff6c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2": {
        "VersionCode": "0ODD6109",
        "VersionQualifier": "",
        "ProductID": "WRAP",
    }
}]
```

When

```
key="a74fff6c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2"
```

and

```
dataObj = {
            "VersionCode": "0ODD6109",
            "VersionQualifier": "",
            "ProductID": "WRAP",
           }
```

I can easily add items using:

```
dataObject = an object with properties
newItem = {}
newItem[key] = dataObj
myJsonObj.push(newItem).
```

How can I remove an item when I have the key as a variable?

This hasn't worked:

```
delete myJsonObj[key]
```

This also hasn't worked:

```
var index = myJsonObj.indexOf(node, 0);
if (index > -1) {
     myJsonObj.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Your array doesn't have any such property.  You need to delete it from an object in the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: FYI "JSON objects" do not exist. JSON is a serialized/textual representation of a Javascript object, which can be used to transfer the object through e.g. an API request. And after deserializing the text, it is a plain Javascript object again (or even a .NET object or JAVA object, depending on what system the recipient was built with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON object is **wrongly constructed**. It should be like this:

```
{
  "a74bb26c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2": {
      "VersionCode": "0ODD6109",
      "VersionQualifier": "",
      "ProductID": "WRAP"
  },
  "a74fff6c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2-unique": {
        "VersionCode": "0ODD6109",
        "VersionQualifier": "",
        "ProductID": "WRAP"
  }
}
```

Notice removed parensis.

You can add items like this:

```
dataObject = an_object_with_properties;
myJsonObj[key] = dataObj
```

After this change your example would work perfectly:

```
delete myJsonObj[key]
```

Here is an example:

```js
const dataObject1 = {
  "VersionCode": "0ODD6109",
  "VersionQualifier": "",
  "ProductID": "WRAP",
}

const dataObject2 = {
  "VersionCode": "0ODD6109",
  "VersionQualifier": "",
  "ProductID": "WRAP",
}

const myJsonObj = {}

myJsonObj['key1'] = dataObject1
myJsonObj['key2'] = dataObject2

console.log('Before delete', myJsonObj)

delete myJsonObj['key1']

console.log('After delete', myJsonObj)
```

Comment: That is invalid syntax.  Objects are not arrays,

Comment: your json is still invalid.

Comment: The trailing commas make the JSON invalid. Also [an array is also valid JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON).

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` is wrongly formatted. You should remove the comma after `ProductID:"WRAP", <--- this comma`. Here is valid `json`:

```
[{
    "a74bb26c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2": {
        "VersionCode": "0ODD6109",
        "VersionQualifier": "",
        "ProductID": "WRAP"
    }
}, {
    "a74fff6c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2": {
        "VersionCode": "0ODD6109",
        "VersionQualifier": "",
        "ProductID": "WRAP"
    }
}]
```

To remove an element. Just use: `JSONArray = JSONArray.filter(obj => !obj[keyToBeFilteredOut]);`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution but I am curious to hear if there are others or if there is a better structure for my array to begin with:

```
newJsonObj = myJsonObj.filter(function (el) { return !el[key]; });
```

Comment: Just check my answer